# characters from notepad file getting converted into special characters while reading using utl_file.get_line procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, non-ascii-characters

I have written a program to read data from a text file and load it into a table using UTL_FILE package in oracle. While reading a few lines some characters are getting converted into special characters, for example:

```
string in file = 63268982_GHC –EXH PALOMARES EVA 
value entered into database = 63268982_GHC âEXH PALOMARES EVA
```

I tried using Convert function but it did not achieve anything.

My Oracle version is 11gR2 and it's using the nls charset WE8ISO8859P1. Because these strings represent physical file names I get a mismatch when I try to match with the filename.

I tried re-converting the value stored in Oracle in WE charset back to ascii like below:

```
convert('63268989_GHC âEXH PALOMARES','us7ascii','WE8ISO8859P1')
```

but the outcome is different from what was there in text file while reading. Can anyone please suggest how this problem can be overcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `–` character in the file is not a regular hyphen (`-`, `chr(45)`) but an [En Dash / U+2013](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013) stored as three bytes, decimal 226, 128, 147 or hex e2, 80, 93. Interpreted individually rather than as a single multibyte character, these correspond to `â€“` as shown [here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

Try opening the file with [`utl_file.fopen_nchar`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_file.htm) and reading lines with `utl_file.get_line_nchar`.

[Oracle 11gR2 Database Globalization Support Guide: Programming with Unicode.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch7progrunicode.htm)